# How to wait for termination of a running function in a gui callback function?

Tags: matlab, control-flow, matlab-gui

My program runs a function when user clicks on an axes object. This function uses the position of cursor and shows its progress as an animation. What I need is to stop currently running call of function when user clicks a new position, and then call the function for this new position.

My code is something like this (in my original code I use `guidata` and `handles` instead of global variables):

```
function TestUI
clc; clear variables; close all;
figure; axis equal; hold on;
xlim([0 100]); ylim([0 100]);
set(gca, 'ButtonDownFcn', @AxisButtonDownFcn);
global AnimateIsRunning
AnimateIsRunning = false;
end

function AxisButtonDownFcn(ah, ~)
C = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
global xnow ynow AnimateIsRunning
xnow = C(1, 1); ynow = C(1, 2);
if AnimateIsRunning
    % ---> I need to wait for termination of currently running Animate
end;
Animate(ah, xnow, ynow);
end

function Animate(ah, x, y)
T = -pi:0.02:pi; r = 5;
global xnow ynow AnimateIsRunning
AnimateIsRunning = true;
for t = T
    if ~((xnow==x)&&(ynow==y))
        return;
    end;
    ph = plot(ah, x+r*cos(t), y+r*sin(t), '.');
    drawnow;
    delete(ph)
end
AnimateIsRunning = false;
end
```

My problem is that any newer clicks interrupt currently running function and keeps previous running `Animate` in a stack. It makes the last drawing of the previous animation remain visible. The worse is that the size of the *stack* seems to be 8 and newer interruptions will be stored in a *queue*! Meaning user can update position only 8 times. To see the problem you can run the code sample above and click on the axes object repeatedly.

Now, I want to check if `Animate` is running in `AxisButtonDownFcn`, and wait for its termination (or terminate it by force), and then call `Animate` with new parameters.

Comment: Do you want to disallow any new clicks until it's done?

Comment: @Suever No, I want to wait for `Animate` to finish its work, it will check `xnow` and `ynow` in next iteration and return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [memyself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561766/memyself) answered the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7531698/2093077), it's impossible to terminate currently running `Animate` *[or waiting for its termination]*, because both `AxisButtonDownFcn` and `Animate` are called in same thread. So available options are:

1. Using **global variables**, which is simple to implement but adds complexity and mutual dependencies. You can find some tricky solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519049/how-can-you-interupt-a-function-from-a-gui-callback-without-adding-an-interupt-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364243/stop-a-gui-in-a-middle-of-process-in-matlab).
2. **Multi-threading**, witch attempts to run processing section and UI interactions in separate threads. It'll be more robust (if you are experienced in working with threads), but needs more coding. There is a detailed implementations for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28378219/2093077).

My solution is based on use of global variables. It's really like the solutions I've already linked to, but both of them are trying to implement start/stop buttons, while I need to stop current process and start a new one at same time:

```
function TestUI
clc; clear variables; close all;
figure; axis equal; hold on;
xlim([0 100]); ylim([0 100]);
set(gca, 'ButtonDownFcn', @AxisButtonDownFcn);
global AnimateIsRunning
AnimateIsRunning = false;
end

function AxisButtonDownFcn(ah, ~)
C = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
global xnow ynow AnimateIsRunning
xnow = C(1, 1); ynow = C(1, 2);
if ~AnimateIsRunning
    Animate(ah);
end;
end

function Animate(ah)
T = -pi:0.02:pi; r = 5;
global xnow ynow AnimateIsRunning
AnimateIsRunning = true;
x = -1; y = -1;
while ~((x==xnow)&&(y==ynow))
    x = xnow; y = ynow;
    for t = T
        if ~((xnow==x)&&(ynow==y))
            break;
        end;
        if ishandle(ah)
            ph = plot(ah, x+r*cos(t), y+r*sin(t), '.');
            drawnow;
            if ishandle(ph)
                delete(ph)
            end
        end
    end
end;
AnimateIsRunning = false;
end
```

It simply prevent `Animate` from being called twice. It calls `Animate` if it's not running, otherwise, it just informs currently running `Animate` that there are new request.